# Revert a revert from a month ago

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I've made a merge a month ago on a repo, then reverted it.

Now it causes me trouble when merging because when I try to merge it deletes some files that has been deleted in the revert, but now I need them. And since the commits that deletes them is more recent than the commit that add them, git delete this files when merging

How can I revert a commit from a month ago that looks like this:

```
... > merge > revert merge (to delete) > other commit to keep > to keep > to keep > ...
```

To this:

```
... > merge > other commit to keep > to keep > to keep > ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the history, which will be a problem for anyone you're collaborating with.

Comment: How can I do that? And how can I make it so it's more easier for the people I'm working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now it causes me trouble when merging because when I try to merge, this merge deletes **some files** that has been deleted in the revert, but now I need them

After merging source code, system has been deleted **some files**: the commit deleting these files is more recently.

To resolve the issue, first, you need to find the commit that you want to revert. I think that you only revert some files in that commit. You use:

```
git revert --no-commit <commit-hash>
```

By default, the reverting changes would be directly committed by Git. With the "--no-commit" option, the changes will only be created, but not committed. You could then edit them further and commit them manually.

You may encounter a conflict source code when you do this action. Please **discard** unrelated files.